# Indexed view with outer joins and sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

My views contains more than million records. To make fast retrieval of data from the view, I plan to use an indexed view. But in my view, I have used sub queries and outer joins. So I'm not able to implement indexed view.

I have these questions:

1. Is it possible to implement triggers on views? If it is a correct way I will insert the views data into one table and I will implement index for that table.
2. Or is it possible to workaround and make the indexed view with sub queries and outer joins?

Please suggest any feasible way

Comment: Do subqueries and triggers really have anything in common?  That is, is there any relationship between the first and second options?

Comment: You can implement triggers on the tables inside of your view to generate the update. 
However, I'd rather try to play with improving performance of your original queries.
Another thing is to look is how do you use your views. If only for reporting, then you can prepare results before running reports.

Comment: A view that uses subqueries and outer joins surely can benefit from indexes. Why do you say it cannot?

Comment: For point **(2)**: try to eliminate those outer joins and/or subqueries from your base view - once you've done that, you can make it an **indexed view** and then you can do your outer joins and subqueries based on that indexed view.

Comment: Have you tried performance tuning against a standard view? Don't skip straight to indexed views - You might be suprised what adding a couple of indexes does. Indexed views rarely work well and are rarely worth the effort

Comment: Triggers on views fire when you attempt DML operations *against the view*. They do *not* fire when changes are made to the *base tables* on which the view is based. I suspect you thought otherwise.

Comment: Off-topic because you have no coding issue at the present, just a performance issue. That sort of question is more suitable for dba.

Comment: But now I see that this is really a continuation of your previous question. You are avoiding the real problem and grasping at straws.